# Disable CRM 2016 to outlook contacts Synchronization

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is there a way I can stop the synchronization of the contact records for CRM 2016 to outlook for every user in the system?
Is there a Global Setting I can set which disables the contact synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a global one button start stop synchronization for all the users. This setting is at a user level as a user could have multiple synchronization filters.

There is a way to update the filter settings for multiple/all users at the same time by using XRMServiceToolBox

XrmServiceToolBox --> Sync Filter Manager (Plugin) --> Users Synchronization Filters (TAB)

Comment: I couldn't find any Global Settings and ended up using the Sync Filter Manager. I do wish there was an OOB Setting in CRM to do this for whole organization.